# Nesting Circles in Google Plus

Tags: contacts, google-plus

Is there a way to nest circles in Google+?

For example, if I have a `Workmates` circle and I want all my workmates to also be in the `Acquaintances` circle. If I add or remove a person from the `Workmates` circle it would automatically be added or removed from the `Acquaintances` circle.

I could not find it, and filed a suggestion. Anyone know if it's possible to do this?

Comment: You can always send Google some [feedback](http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/learnmore/forum/) yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. I have seen several people post such a proposal as a Google+ message, however. I hope that Google is considering it.

There is at least [one guy who is faking it by creating multiple, specially-named circles](http://www.mattstratton.com/tech-tips/how-i-set-up-my-circles-in-google-plus). For instance, he has a "Friends: Online" circle and a "Friends: All" circle. Anyone he drops into "Friends: Online" he also drops into "Friends: All". This'll break down, of course, if he forgets someone.

Here's [a similar approach](https://plus.google.com/103030116155431184588/posts/iu72BpJPtfd).